# Android Fragment Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am trying to learn some Android development with Fragments, but have run into a problem.

My app requires more than one table, so I have taken the approach of creating a main DB adapter to create all the tables and use separate Adapters for each table commands.

The problem I am having is with instantiating the recipe_Adapter in the recipe_Fragment to access the commands in the adapter.
Is there something I need to change to make the Context Fragment friendly?

I think it is neater to have all the Adapters separate, right?
Would it be better to have all the commands for each table in one big main DB Adapter?

When I change the parameters to suit the Fragment - as instructed by Android Studio - I get an error on the following line; the error says that a wrong first parameter is found (ie 'context').
I have tried changing it to Fragment but this gave me even more errors.

**Update Solved!!**
I changed the fragment class below to the working version. I was trying to access the database before the fragment was created and so I was trying to pass something that wasnt there. The new code access the database in the onActivityCreated() in the try and catch statement.

**Main DB Adapter**
    package app.rory.pocket_chef.Adapters;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by Rory on 06/10/15.
 */
public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pocket_chef";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //creating each table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECIPES = "create table if not exists recipes(" +
            "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "name VARCHAR" +
            "ingredents TEXT" +
            "instructions TEXT" +
            "description TEXT" +
            "time TIME)";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST = "create table if not exists shopping_list(" +
            "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            "name TEXT" +
            "quantity FLOAT)";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PUBLIC_DB = "create table if not exists public_db(" +
            "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            "name TEXT" +
            "number INT)";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CURRENT_CONTENTS = "create table if not exists current_contents(" +
            "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            "name TEXT" +
            "quantity FLOAT" +
            "expiry DATE)";

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param ctx
     */
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_RECIPES);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PUBLIC_DB);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CURRENT_CONTENTS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                              int newVersion)
        {
            // Adding any table mods to this guy here
        }
    }

    /**
     * open the db
     * @return this
     * @throws SQLException
     * return type: DBAdapter
     */
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * close the db
     * return type: void
     */
    public void close()
    {
        this.DBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

**Single Table Adapter**

```
package app.rory.pocket_chef.Adapters;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import app.rory.pocket_chef.Fragments.recipes_Fragment;

/**
 * Created by Rory on 06/10/15.
 */
    public class Recipes_Adapter {

    public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
    public static final String INSTRUCTIONS = "instructions";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String TIME = "time";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "recipes";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     *
     * @param ctx
     *            the Context within which to work
     */
    public Recipes_Adapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the recipes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     *
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public Recipes_Adapter open() throws SQLException {
        this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
        this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * close return type: void
     */
    public void close() {
        this.mDbHelper.close();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new recipe. If the recipe is successfully created return the new
     * rowId for that recipe, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
     *
     * @param name
     * @param ingredients
     * @param instructions
     * @param description
     * @param time
     *
     *
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createRecipe(String name, String ingredients, String instructions, String description, String time){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(INGREDIENTS, ingredients);
        initialValues.put(INSTRUCTIONS, instructions);
        initialValues.put(DESCRIPTION, description);
        initialValues.put(TIME, time);
        return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the recipes with the given rowId
     *
     * @param rowId
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteRecipe(long rowId) {

        return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all recipes in the database
     *
     * @return Cursor over all recipes
     */
    public Cursor getAllRecipes() {

        return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID,
                NAME, INGREDIENTS, INSTRUCTIONS, DESCRIPTION, TIME }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the recipe that matches the given rowId
     * @param rowId
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching recipe, if found
     * @throws SQLException if recipe could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor getRecipe(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID, NAME,
                        INGREDIENTS, INSTRUCTIONS, DESCRIPTION ,TIME}, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Update the recipe.
     *
     * @param rowId
     * @param name
     * @param ingredients
     * @param instructions
     * @param description
     * @param time
     *
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateRecipe(long rowId, String name, String ingredients, String instructions, String description, String time){
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(NAME, name);
        args.put(INGREDIENTS, ingredients);
        args.put(INSTRUCTIONS, instructions);
        args.put(DESCRIPTION, description);
        args.put(TIME, time);

        return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) >0;
    }

}
```

**Recipe Fragment**

```
package app.rory.pocket_chef.Fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import app.rory.pocket_chef.Adapters.DBAdapter;
import app.rory.pocket_chef.Adapters.Recipes_Adapter;
import app.rory.slidemenu.R;

/**
 * Created by Z0NEN on 10/22/2014.
 */
public class recipes_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private Recipes_Adapter recipes;
    private DBAdapter db;


    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_layout, container, false);
        return rootview;

    }

    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        recipes = new Recipes_Adapter(getActivity());
        try {
            db.open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error ? compile time error? (if so, you should back to learning java's(OOP's) basics) ... After taking a look into fragment's class hierarchy(see fragment documentation) I do not see that `Fragment` is a subclass of `Context` ... and the questions about how to get context in Fragment where asked bazillion times ... of course you shold know the fragment's lifecycle to get somthing what is real context - not null

Comment: No not a run time error. I updated the question indicating the line where the error has occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, I was trying to access the database before the fragment was created. I added the below code to the fragment class after the onCreate() and it works ok now

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    recipes = new Recipes_Adapter(getActivity());
    try {
        db.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following piece of code:

constructor db

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

construct the database object

```
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_layout, container, false);
DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(rootview.getContext());
return rootview;
```

I don't recommend wrapping a database in an adapter, I would recommend to seperate these concerns to reduce code tangling.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice I will make the changes. Can you tell me how I would go about instantiating in fragments?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html), can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Creating each table... You miss the commas to separate each field.
This is what you want:

```
//creating each table
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECIPES = "create table if not exists recipes(" +
        "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name VARCHAR, " +
        "ingredents TEXT, " +
        "instructions TEXT, " +
        "description TEXT, " +
        "time TIME)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST = "create table if not exists shopping_list(" +
        "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name TEXT, " +
        "quantity FLOAT)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PUBLIC_DB = "create table if not exists public_db(" +
        "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name TEXT, " +
        "number INT)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CURRENT_CONTENTS = "create table if not exists current_contents(" +
        "_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name TEXT, " +
        "quantity FLOAT, " +
        "expiry DATE)";
```

Uninstall and reinstall you app to get the database be recreated.

Comment: Thank you for that, hadnt noticed that at all. Is the approach I am taking the best way of going about the multi table db? and how should I be instantiating adapters in the fragments?

Comment: Have a separate class for your database. Put all the methods there and use them to fill your adapters. Easy.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but I am interested in learning my problems here, I have updated the question telling the problem I have, even if you could point me in the right direction on fixing it that would be great